# Gravity Form Plugin return password strenght unknown

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am having a gravity form which has a password strength indicator. After I type strong password it return

> "Password strength unknown"

**Platform**

- WordPress version `5.2`
- PHP version `7.2`
- gravity form version `2.4.15`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally made changes in functions.php and set a session via jquery ,it is working for me**

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    ?>
        <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        var pwd_str_main =  jQuery("#input_11_29_strength").val();
                        jQuery("#input_11_29_2").keyup(function(){
                                var pwd_str =  jQuery("#input_11_29_strength").val();
                                sessionStorage.setItem('pwd_str_main',pwd_str);
                        });
                        jQuery("#input_11_29").keyup(function(){
                                var pwd_str =  jQuery("#input_11_29_strength").val();
                                sessionStorage.setItem('pwd_str_main',pwd_str);
                        });
                        if(pwd_str_main == "unknown" && (sessionStorage.getItem('pwd_str_main') != "")){
                                jQuery("#input_11_29_strength").val(sessionStorage.getItem('pwd_str_main'));
                        }
                });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```